# QT 4, how do I make a QPushButton assume the maximum width it can take?

Tags: qt4

I have a QGroupBox inside a QSCrollArea.

Inside my groupbox i have a vertical layout with push buttons. How can i make these push buttons get bigger and take up all the room?

Comment: By default QPushButton's size policy expands horizontally to fill unused space. I suspect you aren't setting some size constraints upstream to allow for things to fill the available space and it's not the QPushButtons that are the problem. Could you post the code you're using to build everything?

Answer (score 0):

Buttons by default only expand horizontally.  You'll need to change their sizing policy to also expand vertically, if you want them to fill all the space inside a vertical layout.